# Environment choice for a color-only objects

Tags: texturing, objects, light, vertex-colors

My question will definitely sound incredibly noobish, but I started to play with 3D graphics and Blender just a few days ago (after a month-lasting struggle with OpenGL basics) and I've run into trouble.

I have "created" a nice small bunch of models for a 3D game, determined that I wouldn't use a single texture for the appearence of the objects. This is what they look like:
[image: A bench, house, trees and stones]

Right now I'm trying to create some environment (terrain, lights...), but all of my previous attempts have failed.

1. I tried to create a hill without modifying it´s color. Result: the hill is unrecognizable, it has just the same color as everything else.

[image: Can you see it? I can't.]

2. I played with Z-transparency. Result: better, but nothing delighting.

[image: Huh?! What the hack is this?]

Instead of trying and experiencing failure again, I want to ask: is there any way I could create (a visible) terrain consisting of hills and valleys without using textures? Are there any specific ways of doing things when doing "cartoon graphics"?

Comment: You need to use better lighting. If you have shadows and such, you will see the form better.

Comment: Thank you... Well, I'm a beginner. What does better lighting include? Right now I'm using point lights from several sides of the scene. Do I need to add something special for better shadows?

Comment: Use a sun as main light to get better shadows. A sun is a "all scene" light that has parallel rays from anywhere. Just give it an angle (try 45° to see) and your whole scene has shadows. Add some other types to make things look better here or there.

Comment: reduce sun's size (properties) to get sharper shadows.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Just one more question: if I want "hills" on an adjusted plane to drop shadows, is there something special I've got to do?

Answer (score 1):

- enable Ambient occlusion to get better lighting " you should lower the light source intensity "
- move the light source to get the shadows where you want
- use proportional editing to create hills
- add decimate modifier to get the LOW POLY look

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question